# Trigger no MYSQL para excluir registro quando ultrapassar uma data

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá como poderia fazer para criar uma Trigger que excluísse registros do banco de dados que ultrapassam a data atual do sistema?

Comment: trigger = gatilho, como assim ? explique melhor qq vc precisa

Comment: Na verdade creio que deseja criar uma procedure

Comment: Talvez seja um caso de [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499), se possível, dê uma verificada.

Comment: É eu acho que um procedure para quando a data de termino de uma promoção for menor que a data atual do sistema ele exclui a promoção automaticamente.

Comment: https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Agendamento_de_tarefas_em_MySQL   pesquise por EVENT.